# How to get all siblings of a parent item with specific classes in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have a long list of list items (generated via an API) and I would like to show/hide some of the items with click, something like an accordion effect.

The list items that I would like to hide by default have **P-item** class, and the **M-item** class above them is what it should be triggering them to show.

Here is my markup:

```
<li class="session-item M-item"></li>
<li class="session-item P-item"></li>
<li class="session-item P-item"></li>
<li class="session-item G-item"></li>
```

P-items are children of their parent M-item. So by default in the above example, the two P-items should be hidden and M-item and G-item should be showing.  When M-item is clicked, then the two hidden P-items show. I am only listing 4 items in the above example but the list goes on and the only separator between this relationship is the G-items.

I got it to work but it's only showing/hiding the first direct sibling of M-item, I used `nextElementSibling`, like this:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("M-item");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
```

What's the best way to select all siblings with the P-item and then break, looks for another M-item and repeat?

Is there something similar to `nextAll();` in Vanilla JS? Do I need a `while` loop to iterate over the next sibling?

Here's how my full markup looks like:

[image]

Comment: I'd probably try using a while loop to see if there's another sibling.

Comment: _"P-items are children of their parent M-item"_: not in your example. They're siblings. Did you want to put those `P-item` elements inside the `M-item` elements as a new `<ul>`?

Comment: Hey @Andy , you’re right, I explained it a little weirdly. They are siblings but they should ACT as children of M-item. It’s actually not a bad idea move them or wrap them then I can show/hide the wrap element, hmmm.

Comment: I think it would make for far less complicated code. @hnnnng

Comment: @Andy, wait, I'd still need to find the related siblings to M-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer looks kinda like original, but uses a while loop to hide all following <li> tags as long as they have class .P-item. Loop stops if next element does not have that class, hence only hiding those P-items directly following the M-item that was pressed.
Try it by copy pasting the whole code following here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .M-item {
            background-color: red;
            color: blue;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: pink;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="agenda">
        <li class="session-item M-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item M-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item M-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
        <li class="session-item P-item">something</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("M-item");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                let next = this.nextElementSibling;

                while (next.classList.contains('P-item')) {
                    next.classList.toggle('hide');
                    next = next.nextElementSibling;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly with some very minor tweaks, I used next.classList.toggle('show'); instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP aims to find adjacent siblings with the same class.

One idea would be to intervene a little earlier, before the `li`'s are setup as siblings, and impose an html structure there, grouping the like-classed siblings in `div`'s (or `ul`'s).  But, if we're starting from the already built list, it can be handled as a reduce on the collection of `li`'s...

```js
const sessionItems = document.getElementsByClassName("session-item");

let groups = Array.from(sessionItems).reduce((acc, el, index) => {
  const pItem = el.classList.contains("p-item")
  const delimeter = !pItem || index===0;
  if (delimeter) acc.push([]);
  if (pItem) acc[acc.length-1].push(el);
  return acc
}, []);

// now do whatever we want to the groups, like change visibility
// for clarity in this example, add a color class
groups.forEach((group, index) => {
  group.forEach(el => el.classList.add(`color-${index}`))
});
```

```css
.color-0 {
  color: red;
}

.color-1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="session-item m-item">item A</li>
  <li class="session-item p-item">item B</li>
  <li class="session-item p-item">item C</li>
  <li class="session-item m-item">item D</li>
  <li class="session-item p-item">item E</li>
  <li class="session-item p-item">item F</li>
  <li class="session-item p-item">item G</li>
  <li class="session-item m-item">item H</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the visibility of the P items through CSS only, based on the "active" that the preceding M item has. This means the JS code only has to manage the toggling of the "active" class on the M item:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector(".cad-agenda");
ul.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const mItem = e.target;
    if (!mItem.classList.contains("M-item")) return;
    const wasActive = mItem.classList.contains("active");
    document.querySelector(".active")?.classList?.remove("active");
    mItem.classList.toggle("active", !wasActive);
});
```

```css
.P-item { display: none }
.active ~ .P-item:not(.active ~ .M-item ~ .P-item) { display: block }
.M-item { cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<ul class="cad-agenda accordion accordion-1">
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-1</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-1.1</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-1.2</li>
    <li class="session-item G-item">G-1</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-2</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-2.1</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-2.2</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-3</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-3.1</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-3.2</li>
    <li class="session-item Press-item">PressItem</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-3</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-3.1</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-4</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-4.1</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-5</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-5.1</li>
    <li class="session-item G-item">G-2</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-6 (has no P)</li>
    <li class="session-item -item">empty 1</li>
    <li class="session-item -item">empty 2</li>
    <li class="session-item -item">empty 3</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-7 (has no P)</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-8</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-8.1</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-8.2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

From css set `display: none;` of all elements with class `P-item`

An event listener is placed on all items with the `M-item` class.

When an item with class `M-item` is clicked, the function `myFunction()` is called.

Step 1: Removes all `active` classes.

Step 2: Loop through all the items until it reaches the clicked item. When it reaches the clicked element of the variable `flag`, the value is set to `true`. The `active` class is added to the clicked element and to all subsequent elements with class `P-item`. The loop breaks when it reaches an element with a different class from `P-item`

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const listAll = wrap.querySelectorAll('li');
const listM = wrap.querySelectorAll('.M-item');

listM.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
});

function myFunction() {
    listAll.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove('active')
    });

    let flag = false;
    for (let el of listAll) {
        
        if (el === this) {
            flag = true;
        }

        if (flag) {
            if (el === this || el.classList.contains('P-item')) {
                el.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
};
```

```css
.M-item {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.P-item {
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrap">
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-item Click me</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-item</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-item</li>
    <li class="session-item G-item">G-item</li>
    <li class="session-item M-item">M-item Click me</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-item</li>
    <li class="session-item P-item">P-item</li>
    <li class="session-item G-item">G-item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late arrival.   I've used a data attribute to link parent to child.

```
let count = 0;
  document
   querySelectorAll("[class~=session-item]")
   .forEach((s)=> 
    { 
        if (s.classList.contains("M-item")) {      
            s.addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                document
                  .querySelectorAll(`[data-id='C${this.getAttribute("data-id")}']`)
                    .forEach( (p) => p.classList.toggle("hide") );

              });
              s.setAttribute("data-id", ++count);
        }
        else
        {
              s.setAttribute("data-id", `C${count}`);
        }  
    });
```